# Объединение и сортировка массивов

Tags: c

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, код. Надо слить воедино два массива и отсортировать, появляются ошибки о куче, переизбытке памяти.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void sortit(int array[], int size);
void main(void)
{
    int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0;
    int *array1, *array2, *arraysum;
    printf("vvedite razmenost pervogo massiva : ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    array1 = (int*)malloc(n1 - 1);
    printf("vood pervogo massiva: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        printf("element [ %d] =", i);
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }


    printf("vvedite razmenost vtorogo massiva : ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    array2 = (int*)malloc(n2 - 1);
    printf("vood vtorogo massiva: \n");
    for (int j = 0; j<n2; j++)
    {
        printf("element [ %d] =", j);
        scanf("%d", &array2[j]);
    }
    n3 = n1 + n2;
    printf("%d %d %d \n", n1, n2, n3);
    arraysum = (int*)malloc(n3-1);
    for (int i = 0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        arraysum[i] = array1[i];
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = n1; i<n3; i++)
    {
        arraysum[i] = array2[index];
        index++;
    }
    sortit(arraysum, n3);
    for (int i = 0; i<n3; i++)
        printf("%d ", arraysum[i]);
    system("pause");
}

void sortit(int array[], int size)
{
    int buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i<size;)
    {
        if (array[i + 1]>array[i])
        {
            buffer = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = buffer;
            buffer = 0;
            i = 0;
        }
        else { i++; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё ужасно. Первый же пример: `malloc(n1 - 1);` Почему именно столько?

Comment: На будущее: посмотрите на [valgrind](http://alexott.net/ru/linux/valgrind/Valgrind.html) (если работаете под Linux, конечно - а под чем ещё можно писать на C?).

Comment: Прекрасно пишется в винде на сях :-) Visual Studio неплохо ловит в отладочной сборке проблемы с повреждением памяти и обращениями "не туда".

Comment: И полный стек вызовов от нужного места показывает? Просто там я там практически не отлаживаюсь, захожу только поверить - не пора ли материться и добавлять очередные костыли с  `#ifdef _MSC_VER`... Впрочем, это отдельная тема.

Answer (score 2):

Итак, в коде несколько очень типичных ошибок. Первую заметил @Чад, но предложил неверное решение.

Во всех трех случаях, где выделяется память нужно выделять достаточно памяти. `malloc` не знает о том, что будет хранится в памяти и размер нужно указывать в байтах. Вместо кода вида

```
arraysum = (int*)malloc(n3-1);
```

нужно писать хотя бы так

```
arraysum = (int*)malloc(n3 * sizeof(int));
```

и ещё в двух местах.

Ошибка номер два. Эта ошибка не приводит к явным ошибкам, но в проектах побольше может дать о себе знать. Если память выделили с помощью `malloc`, значит ее нужно освободить. оптимально - после вызова `system` добавьте три строки вида

free(arraysum);

Третья ошибка. В функции sortit. Там цикл от нуля до размер-1. А внутри цикла обращаются не только к текущему элементу, но и следующему. Поэтому на последней итеррации происходит выход за пределы массива. Поэтому, нужно писать как минимум так

```
for (int i = 0; i<size-1;)
```

Кстати, строку `buffer = 0;` можно безболезненно удалить.

Сама функция - очень запутанная реализация сортировки (я с первого взгляда решил, что это не до конца написанная сортировка). В си есть стандартная фукнция qsort, может стоит использовать ее?

Answer (score 0):

```
arraysum = (int*)malloc(n3-1);
```

Вы выделяете памяти на единицу меньше положенного. т.е. у вас индекс у `arraysum[0..n3-2]` и на последнем видимо падает. Вам надо выделить памяти на n3 элементов.